# Get Unique records per attribute in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Student model and I would like to get one record per term_id (one of the attributes).

```
Student.select(:term_id).distinct
```

works but the result is an array of term_ids, not the objects themselves - which is what I would like to get

Comment: `Student.select("DISTINCT term_id")`

Comment: How do I get the ID of the record?

Comment: Is the syntax correct? I get syntax error

Comment: That doesn't make sense, Either you want the distinct fields or some full records, but how do you want AR to choose which record you're interested in when you just want distinct values ?

Comment: I want one record per distinct attribute. I can not see why this does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Student.pluck("DISTINCT id, term_id")
```

Comment: DISTINCT is?   And besides, I would like to get the id of the record

Comment: Latest query  `DISTINCT id, term_id`

Comment: This does not fetch unique term_id, but a unique combination of both

Comment: Then try like `Student.pluck("DISTINCT term_id")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80147/discussion-between-prashant4020-and-tiamon).

Comment: Then please try this `Student.select(:id,:term_id).distinct `

Answer (score 0):

```
Student.select("DISTINCT term_id, `students`.* ")
```

Incase if you are using older versions of ruby (< 2.3.8),

```
Student.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT(term_id), `students`.*")
```

or if you want `id` alone,

```
Student.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT(term_id), id")
```

where students is your table name. You will get array of objects.

Comment: Have you checked the first option  in my answer `Student.select("DISTINCT term_id, \`students\`.* ")`

Comment: Yes, the error message I get is      Couldn't find all Students with 'id': (all, {:select=>"DISTINCT(term_id), id"}